# CSS padding only displays correctly when element is floated

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with a button not displaying correctly, when the element is floated left or right the button displays fine, however if no float is applied the button doesn't display correctly.

I've prepared the following example to demonstrate:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xHvyt

My HTML and CSS are as follows:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="textbox">
        <div class="text">
            <h1>Woop, title</h1>
            <p>content content content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <a href="#" id="wtf" class="button left"><span>Find out more</span></a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="section">
    <div class="textbox">
        <div class="text">
            <h1>Woop, title</h1>
            <p>content content content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <a href="#" id="wtf" class="button middle"><span>Find out more</span></a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="section">
    <div class="textbox">
        <div class="text">
            <h1>Woop, title</h1>
            <p>content content content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <a href="#" id="wtf" class="button right"><span>Find out more</span></a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.section .textbox 
{
    width:25%;
    z-index:2;
    padding:2.5%;
    text-align: center;
  background: #4a8237;
}

.section .textbox  h1
{
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 275%;
    margin:0;
    color:#FFF;
}

.section .textbox .text p
{
    margin:10% 0;
    color:#FFF;
}

.section .textbox .button 
{
    width: 45%;
    text-align: center;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/dUYP3sP.png');
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    color:#FFF;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.section .textbox .button.left
{
    float:left;
}

.section .textbox .button.right
{
    float:right;
}

.section .textbox .button.middle
{
    margin:0 auto;
}

.section .textbox .button span
{
    display: block;
    min-height: 40px;
    padding:10%;
    margin-bottom:10%;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/NvJtuDL.png') no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

As you can see there are three .section divs. In each the ones where the button is floated left/right it displays properly, however when no float is applied it's almost as is the span is not displaying:block;

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There is only one `.section` in that pen, and all the text is `color:#FFF`, making it tough to see what's going on.  You should also list the relevant HTML and CSS here.

Comment: You need to fix your example - you have a malformed `background: background: #4a8237;` declaration preventing the background from displaying.

Comment: if you do not want to float the button then, give float to it's parent section. then that will not create problem for you

Comment: Woops. For some reason the codepen didn't save. I've edited the main post with a new codepen.

Comment: What are these supposed to look like? With the exception of some height/padding-bottom issues they all look the same to me.

Comment: If I'm guessing correctly as to what the problem is, the bad news is that I'm at a loss to explain why it happens, why the bottom margin of the span collapses when it doesn't float. However, I do have a solution: don't float any of them. Just do `margin:0 auto 0 0` for the left one and `margin:0 0 0 auto` for the right one. Then give the `.button` some bottom padding and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from "display:block" to "display:inline-block" seems to fix your problem without concerns about the floats.

```
 .section .textbox .button span
    {
        display: inline-block;
            min-height: 40px;
            padding:10%;
            margin-bottom:10%;
            background: url('http://i.imgur.com/NvJtuDL.png') no-repeat center bottom;
    }
```